# how to make a form load random image in the picture box upon opening the form,make a button show a different image in the picture box

Tags: c#, image, winforms, random

so my friend asked me to make a boobs program, simply its a program that will show a random image, long story short in this program i have 5 images 
what i need to know how to do is
1)make the 4th form show a random image from the 5 images i have all of which ive converted to .png into a single picture box
2)i have a button on there so when i click it, it will show a new image into the same picture box

what i have:
a blank picture box, button, and a windows form, and 5 images in the resource file

all this is being made in visual studio 2019 in c#, and also please be kind as this is my first coding project since highschool, (grad. 2017) so im a little if not very rusty on things XD 
thank you for any and all help!

Answer (score 0):

You could add the pictures in an IEnumerable and shuffle them after each button click and then display the first item of the IEnumerable.

The code would look something like this.

```
var shuffledImages= images.OrderBy(a => Guid.NewGuid()).ToList();
boxImage4 = shuffledImages.First();
```